# Why is mixing Razor Pages and VueJs a bad thing?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core, vue.js

I'm trying to set up a .NET core project using Razor Pages and include vueJs inside the razor page for all my logic.

Something like this:

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "VueJs With Razor";
}
<h2>@ViewData["Title"].</h2>

<div id="app">
   <span>{{ message }}</span>
</div>

<script>
     new Vue({
        el: '#app',
        data: {
          message : 'Hello vue.js'
        }
    })
</script>
```

I have read that mixing Vue and Razor pages is a bad practice, and one should use Razor OR Vue.

Why is this?

Comment: You can't bundle code in razor pages into bundles to improve download time. Also vue is similar to angular as that its made for single page applications, where you got a single html page which loads everything and then everything else happens in browser and via ajax for pure data retrival. No regular http requests to your razor pages like typical in mvc/razor pages

Comment: Use Vue for your front end and write you backend in .net to expose APIs. You'll get a much cleaner app and a better browser epxerience

Comment: I personally don't see the problem. Razor has a specific way of handling things, but in the end is not much different from PHP in the sense that you use it to render front-end code, right? Vue is front-end (javascript) so I don't see the problem, personally.

Comment: Isn't facebook doing this with React?

Comment: I disagree that that Razor can't be bundled. In fact, along with .NET you could say it is it's own bundler. However, unless you use typescript, I would not use Nodejs to install components, but link using CDN. Done this way, Razor has an advantage whereby you can even use partial pages to create reusable components including css styling just thereby skipping the many headaches and huge learning curve associated with the webpack bundler that some SPA lovers neglect to tell you about, but is so crucial to SPA/nodejs web development

Comment: We use vue SFC + razor pages all the time. We basically use vue as much nicer jquery, a lot of the time using vue with an inline template (the template is defined in razor)

Answer (score 34, accepted):

You can do this. Sometimes you're obliged to do it, if, like us, you're migrating an existing code base and you can't convert everything at once. And as Ron C says, it works well.

If you're starting a new project, you have the luxury of choosing. Reasons for favouring an SPA and no Razor would be...

- Reactivity. SPA apps generally feel (much) more reactive. Initial renders are often served from cache, before the data arrives. On first load, all resources arrive in a bundle, in one request-response. There's no, or much less, request chaining.
- Workflow. Webpack, bundling and hot reloads are great. You get production builds, with minification, compilation of Vue render functions, elimination of 404 style errors, js syntax errors are trapped. The cycle from introducing an error to discovering it is greatly reduced for many errors.
- SPA universe. Routing, Vuex, this really is the way of the future.
- Purity. Razor and Vue do similar things at the end of the day. If you mix them, you may have a hard time keeping your head straight.

Comment: SPAs are fine for small projects, but the more complex the project the greater the temptation and risk of monolithic development and I would appreciate a little more honesty when it comes to webpack bundling which I know many people love but neglect to inform people of its huge learning curve. The more components you add (the greater the risk for webpack compilation issues which hamstrings development as I have personally spent days trying to resolve very simple errors that only exist because I'm using webpack

Comment: It has been interesting to have these 2 answers sitting here, and to watch the other answer get 3 times more votes. Webpack monoliths are a problem, it seems, and I don't have good solutions at the moment. Just in terms of developer comfort, the recompile times can quickly grow to outweigh the convenience of hot reloading. F5 never took long! Anyone who knows better, don't hesitate to leave links in the comments. [Here's](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/micro-frontend-architecture-replacing-a-monolith-from-the-inside-out-61f60d2e14c1) an interesting article on Lots Of Small Applications.

Answer (score 141):

**Mixing VueJs and Razor Pages is not necessarily a bad thing, it can be great!**

I use Vue with razor for non SPA pages and the two work well together. I choose to use Vue by loading it via a script tag from a CDN and and I do not leverage the use of WebPack for transpiling, I simply write my code in (gasp) ES5.  I chose this approach for the following reasons.

- Using Razor pages rather than a SPA aids in SEO and search engine ranking of public facing pages.
- Loading Vue directly from a CDN eliminates a whole stack of Webpack  centric technology from the learning curve which makes it much easier for new devs to get up to speed on the system.
- The approach still provides the reactive goodness to UI development that Vue inherently brings to the table.
- By keeping with the “page model”  the code that delivers site functionality is logically grouped around the backend page that delivers that functionality.

Since Vue and Razor can do many of the same things, my goal for public facing pages is to use Razor to generate as close to the final html as possible, and to use Vue to add the reactiveness to the page. This delivers great SEO benefits for crawlers that index the page by parsing the HTML returned.

I realize the my usage of Vue is quite different than going the route of a SPA and WebPack and the approach often means I can't use 3rd party Vue Components without reworking the code a bit. But the approach simplifies the software architecture and delivers a lightweight reactive UI.

By using this approach Razor can be heavily leveraged to generate the initial rendering of the HTML with some tags containing vue attributes. Then after the page loads in the browser, Vue takes over and can reconfigure that page any way desired.

Obviously, this approach will not fit the needs of all developers or projects but for some use cases it's quite a nice setup.

**A few more details for those interested**

Since I use vue sitewide, my global _layout.aspx file is responsible for instantiating vue.  Any sitewide functionality implemented in vue is implemented at this level.  Many pages have page specific vue functionality, this is implemented as a mixin on that page or a mixin in a js file loaded by that page.  When the _layout.aspx page instantiates Vue it does so with all the mixins that I have registered to a global mixin array.  (The page pushed it's mixin on that global mixin array)

I don’t use .vue files.  Any needed components are implemented either directly on the page or if they need to be used by multiple pages then they are implemented in a partial view like the one below.:

dlogViewComponent.cshtml :

```
    @* dlog vue component template*@
    <script type="text/x-template" id="dlogTemplate">
        <div class="dlog" v-show="dlog.visible" v-on:click="dlog.closeBoxVisible ? close() : ''">
            <div class="dlogCell">
                <div class="dlogFrame" @@click.stop="" style="max-width:400px">
                    <i class="icon icon-close-thin-custom dlogCloseIcon" v-if="dlog.closeBoxVisible" @@click="close()"></i>
                    <div class="dlogCloseIconSpace" v-if="dlog.closeBoxVisible"></div>
                    <div class="dlogInner">
                        <div class="dlogTitle" style="float:left" v-text="title"></div>
                        <div class="clear"></div>
                        <div class="dlogContent">
                            <slot></slot>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </script>

    @* Vue dlog component *@
    <script type="text/javascript">
            Vue.component('dlog', {
                template: '#dlogTemplate',
                props: {    //don't mutate these!
                    closeBoxVisible: true,
                    title: 'One'
                },
                data: function () {
                    return {
                        dlog: { //nest the data props below dlog so I can use same names as cooresponding prop
                            closeBoxVisible: (typeof this.closeBoxVisible === 'undefined') ? true : (this.closeBoxVisible == 'true'),
                            title: (typeof this.title === 'undefined') ? '' : this.title,
                            visible: false
                        }
                    }
                },
                methods: {
                    //opens the dialog
                    open: function () {
                        app.hideBusy();        //just in case, no harm if not busy
                        this.dlog.visible = true;
                        var identifyingClass = this.getIdentifyingClass();
                        Vue.nextTick(function () {
                            $("." + identifyingClass).addClass("animateIn");
                            fx.manageDlogOnly();
                        });
                    },
                    //closes the dialog
                    close: function () {
                        fx.prepDlogClose();
                        var identifyingClass = this.getIdentifyingClass();
                        this.dlog.visible = false;
                        $("." + identifyingClass).removeClass("animateIn");
                    },
                    getIdentifyingClass: function () {
                        if (this.$el.classList.length > 1) {
                            //the last class is always our identifying css class.
                            return this.$el.classList[this.$el.classList.length - 1];
                        } else {
                            throw "A dialog must have an identifying class assigned to it.";
                        }
                    }

                }
            });
    </script>
```

In the above, it's the Vue.component('dlog', ... part of the js that installs the component and makes it available to the page.

The vue code on the _layout.cshtml page looks something like the code below.  By instantiating Vue on the _layout.cshtml which is used by the whole site, Vue is only instantiated in a single place sitewide:

_layout.cshtml :

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
    var app = new Vue({
        el: '#appTemplate',
        mixins: mixinArray,                     //The page adds it's mixin to mixinArray before this part of the layout executes. 
        data: {
            errorMsg: ''                        //used sitewide for error messages
            //other data used sitewide
        }, 
        methods: {
            //methods that need to be available in vue sitewide, examples below:
            showBusy: function (html) {
                //functionality to show the user that the site is busy with an ajax request.
            },
            hideBusy: function () {
                //functionality to hide the busy spinner and messaging
            }
        },
        created: function () {
             //this method is particularly useful for initializing data.
        }
    });

</script>
```

What I have provided here paints a pretty clear picture of this non-traditional approach and it's benefits.  However, since several people asked, I also wrote a related blog post: [Using VueJs with ASP.NET Razor Can Be Great!](https://www.giftoasis.com/blog/asp-net-core/vue/using-vue-with-asp-net-razor-can-be-great)

Comment: Any way you could describe this process a bit more, I am wanting to use this method to be able to use the best of both worlds. Some things are fine loaded through razor while others are better loaded dynamically and vue.js is very nice to work with. How exactly do you load/create the components into their respective pages?

Comment: @Insight - I have added more info to my answer, hopefully it provides the extra insights you need.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks Ron! Anyway you could explain a bit more of the _layout.cshtml or show some code?

Comment: @Inisght - I added some _layout.cshtml Vue code with comments. Happy Coding.

Comment: Thanks again! So (probably) last thing! I am assuming you just render the partial pages containing the components into the pages that you need them? Just want to ensure I am understanding.

Comment: Exactly.  Yep, that’s what I do.

Comment: Awesome thanks! I actually ended up expanding on your idea a bit and made a separate folder to hold all my components (for global atleast right now) and I used gulp to compile all the items into a single bundle.js and place the templates into the template: option of the Vue.Component({}). It works beautifully and now I don't have to use partials for site wide components. I am looking to see how I could leverage this to load based on pages too.

Comment: This is very interesting.  I would love to see a full example project to demonstrate this concept.  Perhaps a simple "Todo" app if anyone has time?

Comment: I independently came to the same conclusion you did. A team member found this post and mentioned it. One of the benefits I found is that you can pre-populate many fields then maintain them with vue. This works out great as the initial page load is fast and already contains the data, then vue handles the responsiveness later.  Obviously this take some thinking through to maintain consistency between c# and js models, but add in web api, and it's not bad
ex:
<div v-text"cart.subTotal">@Model.SubTotal</span>
<div v-text"cart.tax">@Model.Tax</span>
<div v-text"cart.total">@Model.Total</span>

Comment: @amsprich exactly.  I’m doing that as well for public facing pages.  I found that for pages behind authentication i wasn’t getting much benefit from pre-population since Vue renders so quickly. So for those pages I just output some Json with the page via c# so that my Vue model has the data for the fields from the initial browser rendering of the page.  Works great and for me was less code to maintain since I didn’t need the code to pre-populate the input fields from the c# side in such cases.

Comment: @ron-c Did you ever write that blog post?

Comment: @MikeCasas - I was waiting to see if there was interest,  would it be helpful?

Comment: @ron-c yes! I get the gist of it from the answer, but was wondering if there was more content somewhere. No pressure. Thanks for the post!

Comment: @flipdoubt thanks that’s encouragement I needed to get serious about my blog article!

Comment: Would love to see a blog post and possibly a github sample project to see how it all comes together. Thank you for this detailed write up.

Comment: @Maverik Thanks, I'm hearing the community loud and clear.  My next project will be to do exactly that, complete with a github sample project.  I'll update my answer with the link to the blog article once completed.

Comment: @RonC any update on the blog post? We're dragging a legacy Web Forms app kicking and screaming into the Century of the Fruit Bat, and would like to see your approach more fully fleshed out. Cheers!

Comment: @wloescher  I've been working on creating a blog platform for our site this past two weeks and almost have it working.  Then I'll write up the post, deploy it, and put the link here, stay tuned. It will remain my focus till task completed :-)

Comment: I was just thinking about this in my recent project, and thats why I googled it.

Comment: I was looking for something similar thanks Ron. To summarize what was said, i think it would be fair to say that Vue can just replace jQuery where you need a bit of interactivity

Comment: @RomaKostelnyy  Sorry for the slow response.  You certainly can replace jQuery with Vue and get some sweet reactivity but I use the two together mostly because I leverage the ajax support in jquery which is very mature.  I wrote this blog article about  [Why I use VueJs and JQuery Together!](https://www.giftoasis.com/blog/vue/why-i-use-vuejs-and-jquery-together) if interested in more details.

Comment: I needed to go down the path of mixin vue with asp.net core 5 recently! Thanks for the info. One question though: What would be the options for authentication/authorization in such a mixed scheme?

Comment: @e4rthdog  For this approach you should be able to use any .NET Core / Razor supported authentication approach.  That's how I do it anyway.  Vue in this approach is kinda an add-on that brings reactivity to the page but access to any page is still ultimately controlled by .NET Core / Razor.

Answer (score 2):

You can now also lint the VueJS templates within the Razor views:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/razor-vue-lint

Answer (score 0):

Great answers and content on this question! Just to add re the OP, the official Vue documentation expressly states that you can mix and match and do what you like with Vue and that it is designed to be used incrementally so I'd say if it fits what you're trying to do then it is NOT an automatic bad practice.