# How to call Vue components in my .cshtml pages?

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, vue.js, razor, vue-component

I have a ASP.NET Core MVC project in conjunction with Vue.js. I am only using Vue.js to make my pages reactive. My goal is to create a main vue instance based on a div in the _layout.cshtml file and then create Vue components using X-Templates and use them around my web app. Worth mentioning that I would like have to have the JS Vue.Component() logic in its own .js file because some of these components will have a good amount of js logic.

The problem that I am having is getting Vue to register/recognize my components when I call them from the .cshtml that I want to use them. I found this stackoverflow post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48707179/7157811) showing how the logic should be to make this work, but his example shows the JS logic inside the cshtml which is something that I am trying to avoid and there is no example on how to call the vue component from another page.

The error that I get is... 
**[Vue warn] Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined**

Tech Stack:

- ASP.NET Core MVC (2.2)
- Vue.js (2.6.10)
- Vue-template-compiler (2.6.10)
- Vue-loader (15.7.0) <-- Not sure if I need this or not.
- Axios(0.18.0)
- Babel/Core (7.4.4)
- Babel/polyfill (7.0.0) <--- My UI must work in IE11 and I use async functions in my JS
- WebPack (4.26.0)

Here is my main _layout.cshtml

```
    <div id="main-app">
     @RenderBody() 
    </div> 
@section Scripts {
    <script src="@Url.Content("~/js/mainVueApp.js")"></script>

}
```

Here is my mainVueApp.js

```
 import Vue from 'vue';
    import myComponent from 'testComponent';

        new Vue({
         el: 'main-app',
         components: {
            myComponent 
            // I also tried, thisIsMyComponent: myComponent. No luck with that either.
          }
       });
```

Here is my _vueTestComponent.csthml

```
    @model TestViewModel 

        <script type="text/x-template" id="my-test-component-id">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header"> My Test Header </div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                           <table class="table"> 
                             <thead> 
                                  <tr> 
                                     <th class="pull-right">
                                       Test Header 
                                     </th>
                                  </tr>
                             </thead>

                             <tbody>
                                <tr v-if="isShowRow"> 
                                     <th class="pull-right">
                                       Test Header AGAIN 
                                     </th>

                                     <tr class="pull-right">
                                         @(Html.Kendo.CurrencyTextBoxFor(m => 
                 m.TestProperty).HtmlAttributes(new Dictionary<string, object>{
                                 {"id", "test-text-box"},
                                 {"class", "textbox-input"},
                                 {"v-model", "testTextBoxValue"}
                                 }).Deferred()
                                 )
                                     </tr>
                                  </tr>
                             </tbody>
                           </table>
                     </div>
                </div>
            </script>
@section Scripts {
        <script src="@Url.Content("~/js/testComponent.js")"></script>

    }
```

Here is my testComponent.js

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import axios from 'axios';

let testComponent = Vue.Component('my-component', {
    template: 'my-test-component-id',
    data: function() {          
       return {
      testTextBoxValue : 'Test Value',
      isShowRow: true
     }

   },
    methods: {
    // Nothing for now....
 }
});

//I tried it without default, but it doesn't work either :(
export default {
testComponent 
};
```

Here is my view that calls the component TestViewForVue.cshtml

```
<div class="row"> 
  <div class="col-12">
      @* Call the Component *@
      @* Do I need to load the .cshtml where this component lives first, as a partial view or something? *@
       <my-component> </my-component>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This is a long answer but long story short cshtml files and razor has nothing to do with vue.js. You most likely need to create a REST api where Vue will pull data from or expose json objects to vue

Comment: I already tested axios inside my new Vue() instance and I can get data back from my APIs and render it on the _layout.cshtml. However, my goal is to create vue components and render those across my UI (inside other .cshtml pages). Not entirely sure, what you mean by your comment.

Answer (score 0):

This changes your structure a little bit(not using the script x-template syntax), but it worked for me. Give this a shot if you can.

Since you want to reuse this component, it might be OK in your case to register it globally.

*Using template literal here, so need to make sure you transpile properly for IE11*

```js
// testComponent.js

Vue.component("my-component", {
  template: `
        <div class="card">
          <div class="card-header"> My Test Header </div>
        </div>
      `,
  data () {
    return {}
  },
  // ...
})
```

Then in your App_Start/BundleConfig.cs, create a bundle for you global components, and render that bundle on your _layout.cshtml render scripts.

```cs
// BundleConfig.cs

public static void RegisterBundles(BundleCollection bundles)
{
  bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/vuecomponents").Include(
    "~/Scripts/VueComponents/testComponent.js"
  ));
}
```

```
// _layout.cshtml

@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/vuecomponents")
```

Now you should be able to include `<my-component />` on any .cshtml pages in your app.

Comment: Do you think it is possible to have the HTML in the cshtml file instead of the js file? I would prefer to have the HTML outside of the JS file. However, I will still try this possible solution and report my findings. Thanks!

Comment: @AdrianCruz It might be possible, but I did not give that shot, sorry. Let me know ^_^