# What options are there to not reload whole page for a file browser on ASP .NET Core Razor page?

Tags: c#, reactjs, asp.net-core, asynchronous, razor-pages

I've got an application written in ASP .NET Core 3.1 that uses Razor pages to display various content.

I have a kind of project details view, where the details of the project are shown like image, description, some fields but also a list of files of the project.

The files of the project I collect using the Graph API (using credentials stored in Configuration/Azure Key Vault) and currently I list them out in a flat list. I store the list of files in my model (in a list with a custom object, to include metadata for the file)

I would like to show the files with folders, so the user only sees the top level folders and files when he opens the page. When he clicks on a folder, the folder should "open" and the user should now see the contents of the this folder (with an option to navigate one level up again).

Honestly, I am not quite sure how to start. I don't want to reload the whole page when the user clicks on a folder and as far as I know there is nothing like an Update Panel in ASP .Net Core that lets me only update parts of a page.

I also programmed some other Reat.JS applications, I know I could create a very dynamic react app to display those files but I am not sure if there is a good way to integrate such a react component in my ASP .NET Core app and also I don't know how I would pass the credentials to this component.

Hope someone can point me in the right direction and give me some tips.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, there is no Update Panel in ASP.NET core MVC, but that doesn't mean you cannot update individual parts of the page. You can use a [View Component](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/views/view-components?view=aspnetcore-5.0) to render just the content of a folder. The following is a list of key things you need to do to implement it:

- Add a MVC action to your controller that returns View Component.
- Enclose the folder content in a container `div` of known `id`.
- Attach JavaScript event listeners to subfolders
- When the user clicks one subfolder the event listener uses the fetch API to call the MVC action.
- The event listener sets `innerHtml` property of the container `div` to the HTML returned by the MVC action
- Attach event listeners to subfolders of recent loaded content.

This approach doesn't require any JavaScript framework or library. It can be implemented with plain vanilla JavaScript.

Probably you will want to add fetch and promise [polyfills](https://polyfill.io/v3/url-builder/).

Comment: Thanks, I will try to follow this approach.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this question is fairly broad and is likely to result in it being closed.  (I didn't vote to close it). The challenge with this question is that there are so many different ways to handle this sort of programming problem.

Using ajax is one very common way to handle this.  Which then brings us to javascript libraries, and there are a bunch of choices.  You mentioned react.  That is one good choice.  If react feels too heavy for you then give [my answer here a read with regard to Vue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48706113/why-is-mixing-razor-pages-and-vuejs-a-bad-thing#answer-48707179). VueJs is extremely lightweight and can easily be used on a single page or on a group of pages. Vue may be a great solution for you.

The main thing to know is that there is no "right" answer to your question which is why unfortunately it's not a great fit for StackOverflow.  Here we prefer questions that have definitive answers.  And this one has none.