# asp.net core <cache/> tag with inline vuejs templates in razor views not working properly

Tags: asp.net-core, vuejs2, razor-pages, asp.net-cache

What I am trying to do is similar to question in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48706113/why-is-mixing-razor-pages-and-vuejs-a-bad-thing)

Main reason for me to have this approach is that my application has a plugin system, so some plugins gets installed at a later time. Each plugin have it's own resources including vuejs logic. Therefore I can't have pre-compiled vuejs like a traditional SPA.

The current approach works well and suitable for my overall architecture and is maintainable as well. However there is something that I came across which I can't understand.

That is if I want to cache a view component that uses  tag helper, after it's being sent to browser vuejs doesn't seem to recompile any vuejs related views inside the cached content. For example;

```
    <cache expires-after="@TimeSpan.FromDays(1)">
        @await Component.InvokeAsync("SiteHeader")
    </cache>
```

Now site header ViewComponent has vuejs in razor like;

```
<script at="Foot" type="text/x-template" id="vue-user-feedback">
     //all html vuejs stuff here
</script>
```

The first time it loads and works, but then next time page loads these components are missing from the browser. If I remove the `<cache/>` it works fine.

Is it because the `<cache/>` instructs the browser to keep the data in browser cache or server as pre rendered html? Even if it's so; once it's loaded to browser shouldn't vuejs be able to find them and recompile?

Comment: The cache tag helper is executed on the server and takes part in the initial generation of the HTML for the page. It is not rendered to the page itself.  The browser knows nothing about the cache tag helper.

Comment: @MikeBrind yes, you are correct. Then the issue remains why VueJS doesn't compile the cached html that gets loaded to browser. That's why I am confused. If I remove the cache tag helper it works fine.

Comment: Seems like no body have came across this issue?